# Number of streams does not match in application with own module language

Tags: android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, buildozer

I am tying to run application with my own language model but I have problem with it.
When I am building demo application from https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo everything is ok, but when I change model included in en-us and file.dic there is a error:
ERROR: "ptm_mgau.c", line 814: Number of streams does not match: 3 != 1
I was follow this tutorial to get own en-us model: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide a complete logcat output.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev : I add a complete logcat output:
part1: https://pastebin.com/h4xpYY5S
part2: https://pastebin.com/Ubx11Vc5
part3: https://pastebin.com/TmNUZ49e
part4: https://pastebin.com/N8ZFtJrk

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The logcat:

```
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/mdef
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/mixture_weights
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/noisedict
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/README
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/variances
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/transition_matrices
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/mdef.txt
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/sendump
I/python  (27924): extracting en-us-ptm/means
```

shows that you forgot to include `en-us-ptm/feat.params` into your application. You did many other strange things too, for example, included large en-us model not suitable for mobile.